# Rotation of a scope round a define point not working

Tags: rotating, tkz-euclide

I want to draw different congruent triangles. Therefore, I'd like to transform and rotate a given triangle.

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetkzobj{all}

\newcommand{\driehoekA}[3]{
\begin{scope}[xshift=#1cm,yshift=#2cm]
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/A, 2/4/B, 7/2/C}
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=orange!30](A,B,C) 
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=1,C=1) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\node at (D)  {$#3$} ;
\end{scope}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzInit[ymax=10, xmax=20]
\tkzGrid
\tkzClip

\driehoekA{0}{0}{F_1}
\begin{scope}[rotate around={10:(D)}]
\driehoekA{4}{5}{F_2}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

Figure 2 is not rotating around the point D in fact D2.

My problem would be solved if I could enter shift= ... , yshift=..., and the rotation angle.

(I also think that my code could be much better?)

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? It does exactly what you asked it to do. It rotated F_2 around the barycenter and when draws it so that the new origin to be in (4,5). If this is not what you want please clarify your question. I also don't understand what the point D_2 is.

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev If you change the angle in rotate around={10:(D)} to 50, 60, 80, ...  it turns around the point D that is defined in the first triangle (F1). I want to move the triangle by x and y and than rotate around the new position.

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev  i think the problem is the order : translation then rotation but it's difficult to rotate around an unknow point.

Answer (score 2):

The problem : you need to do the rotation before the translation but you don't know the centroid... so it's difficult to rotate the triangle around it.

An idea it's to define like in my solution the centroid G outside the macro, then to translate this centroid G' and then rotate around G'.

With only TikZ perhaps you need to look at the notion :
**108.2.4 Saving and Restoring the Coordinate Transformation Matrix**

Here my solution perhaps you need the new version on tkz-euclide [here](http://altermundus.fr/includes/fichiers.php)

```
\documentclass[border=.25cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\newcommand{\driehoekA}[3]{
\tkzDefShiftPointCoord[G](#1,#2){G'}
\tkzDefPointsBy[rotation=center G angle #3](A,B,C){A',B',C'}
\tkzDefPointsBy[translation=from G to G'](A',B',C'){a,b,c}
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=orange!30](a,b,c) 
\tkzDrawPoint(G')
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/A, 2/4/B, 7/2/C}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=1,C=1) \tkzGetPoint{G}
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=orange!30](A,B,C) 
\tkzDrawPoint(G)
\driehoekA{5}{2}{90}
\driehoekA{0}{5}{60}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the extra link to the new mkz-euclide package!